# How to send values from payment page using the server implementation(PHP) of Paypal Checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

I am trying to implement the server integration of PayPal Checkout, as per [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), and setting up a transaction as per [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/).

As far as I understand from other posts the "best" way is by creating 2 routes, using the `createOrder` and `onApprove` methods for creating and validating the executed orders.

I have successfully installed the Checkout PHP SDK and I'm able to launch a transaction using this code:

Client side javascript (checkoutpage.php):

```js
paypal.Buttons({

            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('createorder.php', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                  //  console.log(orderData);
                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },

            //onApprove function below left out for clarity purposes
            onApprove: function(data) {}

}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

and the server side PHP code (createorder.php):

```php
<?php
namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;
require __DIR__ . '/route/to/paypal/autoload.php';
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;

class CreateOrder
{
  public static function createOrder($debug=false)
  {
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body = self::buildRequestBody();

    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    if ($debug)
    {
      echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    return $response;
  }
    private static function buildRequestBody()
    {
        return array(
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' =>
                array(
                    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
                    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel'
                ),
            'purchase_units' =>
                array(
                    0 =>
                        array(
                            'amount' =>
                                array(
                                    'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                    'value' => '2.00'
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
    }
}

if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  CreateOrder::createOrder(true);
}
?>
```

Up to this point the transaction is launched with the data located in the `purchase_units` array in the `createorder.php` page. My question is how can I send those values from the `checkoutpage.php` to the `createorder.php` page, while maintaining the server side PHP implementation? as opposed to setting it up 100% client side like this:

```
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '88.44'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
```

The reason is that the values such as price, number of items, shipping charges, etc can be changed dynamically with JS in the checkout page, while in other instances a static DB value is used.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

Client side:

```js
             createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('createorder.php', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        "intent": "CAPTURE",
                        "purchase_units": [
                            {
                                "amount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "100.00"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                  //  console.log(orderData);
                    return orderData.id;

                });
            },
```

and server side PHP:

```php
<?php
namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;
require __DIR__ . '/route/to/paypal/autoload.php';
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
class CreateOrder
{
  public static function createOrder($debug=false)
  {
    $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
    $request->prefer('return=representation');
    $request->body =  file_get_contents('php://input');
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    if ($debug)
    {
      echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    return $response;
  }
}
if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
  CreateOrder::createOrder(true);
}
?>
```